# How does jumping from class to class in python work?

Tags: python, class, object, inheritance, methods

This question is based on Zed Shaw's *Learn Python the Hard Way*, exercise 43. In this exercise Zed is jumping from class to class and my question is how does this work?
There are two things that are confusing me:

1. The fact that the, return 'death', returns the class 'Death'. The 'd' in 'death' before return is lowercase, but the actual class name begins with an uppercase "D". Why does that still work?
2. The fact that the, return 'death' is in quotes. Why does that work, but:

   ```
   def function():
       Variable = "This is a variable."
       return 'variable'

   print function()
   ```

only returns the string 'variable'.

Some examples are:

```
        print "putting him down, then jump through the Weapon Armory door."
        return 'laser_weapon_armory'
```

This choice leads to a class that is stylized "LaserWeaponArmory".

```
     print "bridge where you must place it in the right spot."
     return 'the_bridge'
```

This returns a class the is typed "TheBridge".

**Link to full exercise:**

http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex43.html

Thanks.

Comment: No classes are returned; only strings.

Answer (score 0):

Python is not doing any such conversion. The string that is returned is mapped to the object manually using the `Map` class, which is described just before the "What You Should See" section.

This is the actually code that is used in the `Engine`:

```
next_scene_name = current_scene.enter()
current_scene = self.scene_map.next_scene(next_scene_name)
```

`next_scene_name` is a string and the next line retrieves the class that is defined in the `Map` for this string.